# Why is this an invalid operand?

Tags: assembly, nasm, opcode, operand

I have the following ASM file generated by a compiler I'm writing:

```
; This code has been generated by the 7Basic
; compiler <http://launchpad.net/7basic>

; Uninitialized data

      SECTION .bss
v_0 resb 4
v_4 resb 4
v_8 resb 4

; Code

      SECTION .text
push 1
pop eax
mov v_0, eax
push 2
pop eax
mov v_4, eax
mov eax, v_0
push eax
mov eax, v_4
push eax
pop ebx
pop eax
imul eax,ebx
push eax
pop eax
mov v_8, eax
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

> test.asm:16: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
>   test.asm:19: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
>   test.asm:29: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

This really doesn't make sense because according to the NASM docs, I'm allowed to:

> MOV    mem_offs, reg_eax    386

Why can't I perform this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need square brackets to dereference the pointers:

```
mov  [v_0], eax
```